# How to find triangle vertices given midpoints?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a task to find vertices if midpoints are given: $M1(2;1)$, $M2(5;3)$, $M3(3;-4)$. I know one way to solve it through making a system of equations with three variables.

My teacher says there is faster way by using the midline of a triangle, and I can`t find this way of solving it on the Internet. How can I do it?

Comment: If the vectors from the origin to the vertices are $\vec{v}_i, i=1,2,3$, then the vector to the midpoint of the edge opposite to the vertex $\vec{v}_k$ is $\vec{m}_k=\frac12(\vec{v}_i+\vec{v}_j)$ where $i,j$ are the two indices distinct from $k$. So if $i,j,k$ are $1,2,3$ in some order we see that
$$\vec{v}_i=\vec{m}_j+\vec{m}_k-\vec{m}_i.$$ Fast enough, but not what your teacher was talking about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A parallelogram forms between the midpoints and each vertex; the lengths of opposite sides are equal, so equate the x and y values of the vertices from there:

[image: Here's an example]

You can see that the "rises" and "runs" are the same, so in this example we're finding B visually, the difference between $x_{E}$ and $x_{D}$ is $3$, so we go to F: $3-3=0$ which gives $x_{B}$. You do the same for the y value: $3-1=2$, go to F; $-4-2=-6$. $$B(0,-6)$$

Comment: This gives $B=D+F-E=(2,1)+(3,-4)-(5,3)=(0,-6)$ as in my answer, so the answers agree. (+1)

Answer (score 10):

The matrix equation giving the midpoints from the vertices is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac12&\frac12&0\\
0&\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&0&\frac12
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\vphantom{\frac12}\\b\vphantom{\frac12}\\c\vphantom{\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a+b}2\\\frac{b+c}2\\\frac{c+a}2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Inverting the equation above yields
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&1\vphantom{\frac12}\\
1&1&-1\vphantom{\frac12}\\
-1&1&1\vphantom{\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a+b}2\\\frac{b+c}2\\\frac{c+a}2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\vphantom{\frac12}\\b\vphantom{\frac12}\\c\vphantom{\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The last equation simply says
$$
a=\frac{a+b}2+\frac{c+a}2-\frac{b+c}2\\
b=\frac{b+c}2+\frac{a+b}2-\frac{c+a}2\\
c=\frac{b+c}2+\frac{c+a}2-\frac{a+b}2
$$
This amounts to reflecting each midpoint across the midpoint of the line connecting the other two midpoints.

Comment: Love this one!!

Answer (score 8):

Anoher elementary construction is this: Guess a point $A_0$, reflect it to find $B_0$, reflact that to find $C_0$, reflect that to find $A_1$, which will differ from $A_0$. But the midpoint of $A_0$ and $A_1$ is the true $A$.

Comment: Brilliant +1.   .

Comment: What a wonderful way. Is there any proof or logic behind it?

Comment: I can prove it now. Proving it is easy but re-apply the result to do some useful is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

By a construction procedure: Draw a line parallel to $M_2 M_3$ through $M_1$ and same for other two pairs, to find three  intersection  points $A_1, A_2, A_3.$

To translate this into vectors:There are 3 vectors. $ A, B, B-A $. Find their position vectors. The other 3 vector triangles drawn around them are labelled same between $A_1, A_2, A_3$ to fix their coordinates with parallel displacement.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex opposite to $M_1$ is the reflection of $M_1$ in the midpoint of $M_2M_3$.